# run time issue in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.7

I can't able to run the selenium python code in pycharm and i can't able to open the chrome

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\MNM\Desktop\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("google.com")
```

The error message is

line 2

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\MNM\Desktop\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
                         ^
```

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the compilation error message you will see `PEP 8: invalid escape sequence '\c'`

You can use double `\` to escape string

```
webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\MNM\\Desktop\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Or use `r` before the string to indicate it's string literal

```
webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\MNM\Desktop\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
```